# Selecting columns based on aggregation in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with the following 5 character variables (Publisher, Platform, Genre, Rating, Global Sales), i would like to fliter it to get the top 30 Publishers based on their global sales,  so in the end, i would like to have a table with 4 variables and 30 records ( Publisher (top 30), Platform, Genre, Rating).

Comment: If your data frame has _exactly_ the names in _exactly_ this order, and "Global Sales" is _definitely_ numeric, and your data frame is called `df` you could do `df[order(-df$'Global Sales'),][1:30, 1:4]`. If this doesn't work for you, then you really need to show us a sample of your data frame.

Answer (score 0):

using {[dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/)} and the pipe operator for convenience and legibility:

```
df %>% 
    slice_max(`Global Sales`,  n=30) %>%
    select(-`Global Sales`)
```

Comment: Thanks IO, i will check this code, by the way is your name inspired by a video game character ?

Comment: just my initials :-)